# gstreamer-sharp compilation : where to find glib-sharp 2.99.4?

Tags: c#, gstreamer, configure

I am running into a lot of trouble lately with gstreamer-sharp. I fail to compile it.

I am downloading the source from this github repo : https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp

The ./autogen.sh command fails with the following error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-sharp-3.0 >= 2.99.4) were not met:
Requested 'glib-sharp-3.0 >= 2.99.4' but version of GLib is 2.99.3
```

So then I downloaded gtk-sharp from their repo (https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp) because I could not find version 2.99.4 on my debian distrib.
I built it without issues, and installed it too. I have indeed the glib-sharp.dll amongst other, and I've installed it. But I still get the same error.
I even tried this command

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/qrthur/build/gtk-sharp ./autogen.sh
```

Where I am certain I have my glib-sharp dll. But it still fails with the same error.

Some people managed to compile gstreamer-sharp-0.99 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For gstreamer-sharp 0.99 you will need gtk-sharp 2.99.2 If you want to compile gstreamer-sharp master you will need gtk-sharp master as well.

Comment: I managed to compile gstreamer master with gtk-sharp master, thanks. However, for gstreamer 0.99 I still did not find a way to make it build!